# To render ui:include on basis of screen width

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, uiinclude

Is it possible to render  on basis of screen width?
For example on desktop the header is normal but on mobile devices, render mobile header.
Is there some way I can achieve this USING JSF or JQUERY?

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries(CSS) for responsive layout.